# Constraining UITableViewCell to change when editing

Tags: swift, uitableview, uikit

I have a UITableViewCell that has a UIImageView 20 pts in from the left. When I tap "Edit" to edit the contents of my UITableView and the red edit circle comes in from the left, how do I properly set up my constraints so the left of my UIImageView is constrained to the right of that red edit circle view?

Note: I'm doing layout in code, not using Storyboards or xibs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would be handled automatically if you make sure that your views are subviews of the `contentView` in the `UITableViewCell` and your constraints are applied to the `contentView`.

Comment: Thanks Infinity James